# How to solve quadratic matrix expression using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I have the following quadratic equation

```
C_1=S*C*U
```

where `C_1` and `C` are known matrices and `S` is the transpose matrix of `U`, how can I find the matrix `U` in Matlab? Is there a function that helps me to find it?

Comment: Is C upper triangular?

Comment: C is a diagonal matrix with the diagonal equal to [1,1,0]

Comment: Not necessarily, C_1 has the following form: [c_1,c_2,0; c_2,1,0; 0,0,0]

Answer (score 0):

You have given very little detail about the nature of your matrices, but if `C_1` is square and symmetric, then the following holds:

```
C_1 = U * D * (U')
```

Where the prime `U'` denotes the transpose of `U`. Here, `D` is the diagonal matrix of `C_1`'s eigenvalues and `U` is the corresponding matrix of eigenvectors.

Take the following example:

```
C_1 = [3     0     5
       0     1     6
       5     6     4];
[V, D] = eig(C_1);
% now V*D*(V') = C_1
```

So if `C_1` is square and symmetric, and `C` contains its eigenvalues, the answer to your question is:

**`U` is the matrix of eigenvectors of `C_1`**, and you can find it using the [`eig` function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html).

See the [matrix cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf) section 5.3.1 for details.

Comment: but in this case D is not equal to the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is equal to [1,1,0] because [1,1,0] are not necessarily the eigenvalues of C_1

Comment: By the way, I just added more informations about C_1 in the comments